# Using OR with COUNTIFS

Tags: excel, countif

I saw few examples here but on my side none of them is working. It might be that I have more than two possible choices to use within the OR function (I am not sure).

I need `COUNTIFS(K:K,{"2","99"},I:I,{"10","15","20","30","35"},B:B,"Y023*",G:G,Z2+1)` to make it work

is this possible to calculate **without writing multiple** `COUNTIFS???`

```
Column K count it IF there is 2 OR 99 
AND
Column I IF ANY OF 10,15,20,30,35
AND
Column B Starts With "Y023"
AND
Column G is Equal on Z2+1
```

EDIT:
Including Screenshot
[image]

In the formula bar, if I change "Status!K:K, {"2";"99"}" it shows me 0, if I leave it as in the image it works but than again I need to add the same formula with Status "99".

EDIT - SOLUTION - as per @Tom Sharpe answer, please see below

```
{=SUM(COUNTIFS(Status!G:G,K2+1,Status!K:K,{"2";"99"},Status!I:I,{"35","30","20","15","10"}))}
```

Above is entered as an array formula and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also try

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(K:K,{"2";"99"},I:I,{"10","15","20","30","35"},B:B,"Y023*",G:G,Z2+1))
```

Note that the comma between "2" and "99" has been changed to a semicolon. This forces the COUNTIFS to work through all the combinations of the two lists in curly brackets, but as mentioned by @Forward Ed, it will be computationally expensive if used on whole columns but less so than an array formula.

In the example below, Z2 is set to 1

[image]

Comment: OK, I tried with comma and semicolon also, but its only counting the I:I where 10 and its not counting the rest. Im trying now different combinations with comma and semicolons on both column to see if I can make it work.

Comment: So, at the moment only counts the combinations with K:K="2" and I:I="10" but it needs to include all rows with K:K="2" (with any of I:I= 10,15, 20, 30, 35) and again all rows with K:K="99" (with any of the same numbers). I am entering this as an array formula

Comment: Unfortunately I can't make it fail with my own test data even when not entered as an array formula. Is it possible to provide some of your test data or a screen shot?

Comment: Have you definitely included the SUM around the COUNTIFS?

Comment: @TomSharpe  why the need for the sum?  does COUNTIFS return an array of result based on the {}?

Comment: I've included a screenshot, the data is on multiple sheets so I tried to simplify it. Status is the Name of the Sheet that I am using as well as Consolidated Orders. @Forwar Ed, COUNTIFS is returning an array, that why is needed SUM as wrapper

Comment: In your screenshot here, there should be some values with 99 in column G, and these also should be calculated  if column I has 10,15,20... etc but NOT included if any other value than 2 or 99

Comment: Well no, the goalposts seem to have changed, in OP it was K:K that had 2,99 in it and G:G just had a single value to be matched, Z2+1. Now you've got G:G to be matched on K2:L2+1 and that's the bit that's stopping it from working. Now you'd have to use Transpose(K2:L2+1) AND enter it as an array formula to get anywhere.

Comment: @Forward Ed, yes, the key to this is to get the COUNTIFS to return an array. If you have two lists, then one must be a column and the other a row so you force it to produce  2d array.

Comment: @TomSharpe - K2:L2 is merged, it is a date format and only one value stored. I believe that if I take only K2, the same date value will be returned.

Comment: @TomSharpe - I've amended the previous formula and tried only with K2 instead K2:L2 (merged), I cant say the difference but now worked. I'll add your solution in the question on the top also. Anyway thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

`=SUMPRODUCT(((K:K=2)+(K:K=99)),(I:I=10)+(I:I=15)+(I:I=20)+(I:I=30)+(I:I=35),(LEFT(B:B,4)="Y023")*1,(G:G=Z2+1)*1)`

Comment: While the sumproduct formula does work, it is an array formula.  It is my understanding that with array formulas, full column references should be avoided due to excessive computational effort.  As such, where possible, the range should be limited to just the required data.

Comment: With SUMPRODUCT I got #VALUE!, possible mistype in my formula, I'll double check and let you know

Comment: Change the last part of the sumproduct from (G:G="Z2+1)*1 to G:G=(Z:Z+1) i suspect.

Answer (score 0):

u can divide the problem in to two parts which will make it easier to handle:

1- use Column L to create logical function, L2 for example would have this formula
IFERROR(AND(MATCH(K2,{99,22},0),MATCH(I2,{10,15,20,30,35},0),SEARCH("Y023*",B2),G2="Z2+1"),FALSE)
explanation:

- AND() will force all your cells in the same row to have the values
  you specify
- Match will provide you with OR() option in the cell
- Search will help u in the starting of string
- Iferror  is used since the Match and search would give you an error

2- Countif(L:L,True)

Hope this helps